# Riemannian homogeneous equivalent to linear group orbit

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Let $ M $ be a smooth manifold.

Recall that a manifold $ M $ is smooth homogeneous if there exists a Lie group acting transitively on $ M $.

Recall that a manifold $ M $ is Riemannian homogeneous if it admits a metric with respect to which the isometry group is transitive, moreover this metric can always be chosen to have nonnegative curvature.

And recall that a manifold $ M $ is a linear group orbit if there exists a representation $\pi:G \to GL(V) $ and a vector $v \in V$ such that the orbit of $ v$
$$
\mathcal{O}_v:=\{ \pi(g)v:g \in G\} 
$$
is diffeomorphic to $ M $.

The fundamental group of a linear group orbit is always finite by abelian (i.e. has finite commutator subgroup):

[How bad can $\pi_1$ of a linear group orbit be?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206618/how-bad-can-pi-1-of-a-linear-group-orbit-be)

And the fundamental group of a Riemannian homogeneous space is also always finite by abelian (i.e. has finite commutator subgroup):

https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/theoretische_mathematik/diffgeo/mr1783960.pdf

This condition on the fundamental group holds in both cases for essentially the same reason. In both cases the manifold $ M $ is the total space of a vector bundle (the vector bundle is trivial if $ M $ is Riemannian homogeneous see [noncompact Riemannian homogeneous is trivial vector bundle over compact homogeneous](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410334/riemannian-homogeneous-always-trivial-vector-bundle-over-compact-homogeneous) but possibly nontrivial if $ M $ is a linear group orbit) over a compact Riemannian homogeneous base $ B $. And thus $ M $ deformation retracts onto $ B $. And a quotient of compact groups always has $ \pi_1 $ with finite commutator subgroup (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321106/transitive-action-by-compact-lie-group-implies-almost-abelian-fundamental-group/4359177#4359177).

Are the following three properties equivalent?

- $ \textbf{(1)} $ $ M $ is Riemannian homogeneous
- $ \textbf{(2)} $ $ M $ is a linear group orbit
- $ \textbf{(3)} $ $ M $ is smooth homogeneous and $ \pi_1(M) $ has finite  commutator subgroup

How about if we assume $ M $ compact? In other words, are the following three (actually four I added one) properties equivalent:

- $ \textbf{(cc)} $ $ M $ admits a transitive action by a compact Lie group (so a fortiori is compact)
- $ \textbf{(1c)} $ $ M $ is compact and Riemannian homogeneous
- $ \textbf{(2c)} $ $ M $ is compact and a linear group orbit
- $ \textbf{(3c)} $ $ M $ is compact and smooth homogeneous and $ \pi_1(M) $ has finite  commutator subgroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \textbf{(1)} \implies \textbf{(2)} $

Up to diffeomorphism a Riemannian homogeneous space is just a trivial vector bundles over a compact Riemannian homogeneous space ([noncompact Riemannian homogeneous is trivial vector bundle over compact homogeneous](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410334/riemannian-homogeneous-always-trivial-vector-bundle-over-compact-homogeneous)). Compact Riemannian homogeneous spaces are linear group orbits ([Compact linear group orbit equivalent to linear compact group orbit](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409511/compact-linear-group-orbit-equivalent-to-linear-compact-group-orbit/409532#409532)) and vector spaces are linear group orbits and cartesian products of linear group orbits are linear group orbits so $ M $ Riemannian homogeneous implies $ M $ a linear group orbit

$ \textbf{(2)} $ is strictly weaker. The tangent bundle of $ S^2 $ is nontrivial so cannot be Riemannian homogeneous. However it arises as a linear group orbit by consider the orbit of the vector $ (1,0,0) \in \mathbb{C}^3 $ with respect to the standard representation of $ SO_3(\mathbb{C}) $.

$ \textbf{(2)} \implies \textbf{(3)} $

See [How bad can $\pi_1$ of a linear group orbit be?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206618/how-bad-can-pi-1-of-a-linear-group-orbit-be)

$ \textbf{(3)} $ is strictly weaker. The Moebius band has abelian $ \pi_1 $ and a transitive action by $ SE_2 $ but is not a linear group orbit (I think, actually that claim is open here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4359525/is-it-possible-to-realize-the-moebius-strip-as-a-linear-group-orbit but at least we can be sure that the Moebius strip is not Riemannian homogeneous since it is a nontrivial vector bundle)

$ \textbf{(cc)} \implies \textbf{(1c)} $

Since $ M $ admits a transitive action by a compact group $ K $ then $ M $ is compact and $ K $ can always be taken to act by isometries ( by pushing forward the biinvariant metric on $ K $ to a left invariant metric on $ M $).

$ \textbf{(1c)} \implies \textbf{(2c)} $

Since $ M $ is compact then $ K=Iso(M) $ is compact so $ M $ is a quotient of the compact group $ K $ and thus by Mostow-Palais $ M $ is a linear group orbit.

$ \textbf{(2c)} \implies \textbf{(cc)} $

If $ M $ is assumed compact and $ M $ is a linear group orbit of some group $ G $  then the maximal compact subgroup of $ G $ acts transitively see [Compact linear group orbit equivalent to linear compact group orbit](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409511/compact-linear-group-orbit-equivalent-to-linear-compact-group-orbit/409532#409532) . Thus we have

$$
\textbf{(cc)}=\textbf{(1c)}=\textbf{(2c)}
$$

Now for

$ \textbf{(cc)}=\textbf{(1c)}=\textbf{(2c)} \implies \textbf{(3c)} $

The three equivalent conditions above imply that $ M $ is compact, admits a transitive action by a Lie group, and has finite by abelian fundamental group, see either of the first two links in the question or see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321106/transitive-action-by-compact-lie-group-implies-almost-abelian-fundamental-group

$  \textbf{(3c)} \implies  \textbf{(cc)}=\textbf{(1c)}=\textbf{(2c)} $

True  for dimension 2. True for dimension 3. Not sure in general!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is true if $M$ is compact with finite fundamental group. A theorem of Lichnerowicz says that the isometries of a riemannian manifold $M$ is a Lie group $G$. If $G$ acts transitively on $M$, there exists a compact subgroup of $H$ of $G$ which acts transitively on $M$ (your previous question). A Lie compact group is a subgroup of $SO(n)$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905118/what-class-of-lie-groups-embed-in-a-general-linear-group

Comment: Just because $ M $ is compact and $ G $ acts transitively does not mean that a compact subgroup $ H $ of $ G $ acts transitively (for example the $ G=E_2 $ acts transitively on the Klein bottle $ M=KB $ but no compact subgroup acts transitively). My previous question only proved that for the case of $ M $ compact with finite fundamental group. But thanks for teaching me something about the theorem of Lichnerowicz! I was looking it up and found that the isometry group of a compact Riemannian manifold is always a compact group! So that directly solves the case for $ M $ compact as you say